# django add url parameter in a view function

Tags: django, django-urls, url-parameters

I am building a follower list view, frontrend allows user to search followers on a specific user by `request.GET`

After adding the pk on the url in frontend, we use something like `/?user=2` To find all followers of user 2.

Here’s the issue. The frontend must have `user` parameter to indicate who you searching, show a user card in the search box. And the backend, if there is no `user` Param set, will target followers of `request.user`.

When the url is `/`, I am actually going for `/?user=request.user.pk`, can I add this parameter in view function? Or how can I re-parse the url and call the view function again when default?

Something to add manipulate param before redirect

```py
def userFollowerView(request):
    user = request.GET.get('user', None)
    if not user:
        request.path.setParam('user', request.user.pk)
        return userFollowerView(request) # or redirection
    return ...
```

---

The reason I am not using a regex pattern to indicate `user` Pk and another url for redirection, is that, this is a minimised example, in real life I am dealing with a pk list on other scenario that must be passed as url param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using redirect() with the help of f-string like this:

```
def userFollowerView(request):
    user = request.GET.get('user', None)
    if not user:
        return redirect(f'/<your_url>/?user={request.user.id}')
    # Below this have your URL's default code
```

This would work as you intend it to be, the URL will load with the requested user's id

---

Solved by

```py
def userFollowedView(request):
    try:
        # support list param: &tag=2&tag=3 => [2, 3]
        users = list(map(lambda x:int(x), dict(request.GET)['user']))
        profiles = Profile.objects.filter(user__prof_followed_set__in=users)
    except KeyError:
        p = request.build_absolute_uri()
        if '?' in p:
            p += f'&user={request.user.pk}'
        else:
            p += f'?user={request.user.pk}'
        return redirect(p)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however, my route can have some parameters already, I wonder if there is a way to set url parameter other than f string

Comment: I don't think so there is any other way to set the URL parameters as you have to send the URL through the backend, you either use render() for it or redirect. You can achieve a bit more using Javascript. You can try that, but I guess this does adequate job.